# Canonical answer for PHP within JavaScript questions

Tags: discussion, canonical

If you're following the PHP tag you'll see multiple questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179961/changed-php-code-with-selector-html-doesnt-execute) coming up on a daily (sometimes even hourly) basis.

Those questions are most likely:

> I include this PHP code into my JavaScript, why isn't it executed but displayed as a string?

It often happens that some, mostly lower rep users as far as I observed, answer these questions instead of closing those as duplicates.

I, for myself, want to keep Stack Overflow clean, but I'm missing a canonical answer for this. Is there already one that could be used? This question is a pretty basic question that comes up if you've no clue about server- and client-site-execution of code.

Almost all of those question would be answered with an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) approach.

EDIT:

Just found out that my question for a canonical answer is a duplicate, I already marked and closed it as such.

Comment: I've see people use [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). Not sure it's the greatest, but it does cover the concepts they lack.

Comment: Madara Uchiha wrote a canonical for that.. [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: I think that the one from Alexander is bester, because it's more understandable for Users that don't understand this. For further reading the one from Josh is pretty well, but Alexanders one referes to that one

Comment: Side note: "instead of closing those as duplicates" - the real problem is negative incentive to close as duplicates... So barely anyone really trying to find duplicates (any tag).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry, I didn't understand your comment, could you clarify please?

Comment: @KhorneHoly there's no incentive to close as a duplicate if you can answer and possibly get upvotes/reputation

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I'm just feeling sad if I see that answers to such questions get 10 upvotes. This is clear duplicate, such questions are asked permanently. I'm going to mark those as duplicates, I just hope that I'm note the only one that does so.

Comment: @KhorneHoly Thank you for your efforts, I gave up long ago, it's a losing effort.  I think what SO needs to do is remove all gained reputation if a question is subsequently marked as a duplicate

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I think a more valuable solution would be to effort the ones that mark a question as a duplicate. I'd rather stay at my relative low rep that to earn dirty internet points. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the suggestions from Alexander and Josh I'll use the [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) question to mark such questions as duplicate.

I personally find this question more understandable for new programmers in this particular field.

The [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) question is more detailed, but also get referred to from the other question for additional information.

I hope that other users of Stack Overflow will use this questions to also mark duplicates instead of answering them over and over again.